# How to temporarily disable a href click after a click eventListener is applied

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a javascript tool that applies a click eventListener to a span for opening a tooltip. This click only actually does something when some toggle is set to `true`. If the toggle is set to `false`, a click does nothing. However, when the toggle is on and the span already is part of a `<a>`-tag, the span basically has 2 click behaviors. How can I temporarily disable the link click when the toggle is set to `true`?

Below is what I currently have.

```
<a href="#">Some <span class="tooltip">text</span></a>
```

```
function createTooltips() {
  const spanElements = document.querySelectorAll(".tooltip");
  spanElements.forEach((spanElement) => {
    spanElement.addEventListener("click", openToolTip);
}

function openToolTip() {
  if (toggledOn == true) {
    ...open the tooltip...
  } else {
    return
  }
}

function setToggle() {
  ...
}
```

I found some solution here that remove a click entirely. Also I tried to apply a `pointer-events: none;` style to the span, but this will disable my own applied click eventListener.

Comment: Add a click event listener to the `<a>`. If the click should be disabled, it should call `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: If the span is inside the anchor, you can call `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the click from bubbling out to the anchor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The `event.preventDefault()` does it's work by disabling the click. But is there a way to undo this?

Comment: And on `event.stopPropagation()` the documentation says "It does not, however, prevent any default behaviors from occurring; for instance, clicks on links are still processed.". So that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "undo this"? It only affects the current click. If you don't call `event.preventDefault()` on the next click, it will follow the link.

Comment: This call should be in the `if` block, so you only prevent the click from following the link when you display the tooltip.

Comment: I'm currently trying to implement the `event.preventDefault()` in my actual code. But I still have a question: if I apply the `event.preventDefault()` to the `<a>` when the toggle is on. What will happen when later I toggle it off? It doesn't remove the `event.preventDefault()` from the `<a>`, is it?

Comment: There's nothing to remove. It doesn't change anything about the element, it just prevents the current event from continuing to its default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event listener on the anchors that checks the toggle flag. If the tooltip is toggled on, use `Event.preventDefault()` to prevent that click from following the link.

```js
function createTooltips() {
  const spanElements = document.querySelectorAll(".tooltip");
  spanElements.forEach((spanElement) => {
      spanElement.addEventListener("click", openToolTip);
      spanElement.parentElement.addEventListener("click", checkToggle);
    }
  }
}

function openToolTip() {
  if (toggledOn) {
    // ...open the tooltip...
  }
}

function checkToggle(e) {
  if (toggledOn) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```